# why this error coming when i am creating a container by using dockerfile?

Tags: python

docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "tomcat9": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Comment: What's the connection to Python? What does your Dockerfile look like?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.